# Link between vee/hat operators and exp/log maps

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

I am studying some concepts of differential geometry in order to apply to a robotics topic.

I am a bit confused on the link between vee/hat operators and exp/log maps.

I know that:

The concepts of *vee* and *hat* operators are strictly related to the *exp* and *log* maps. They respectively allow to go from a $n$-dimensional Lie Group to a Lie algebra associated to an $n$-dimensional vector space and back. The *vee* operator has been associated to the symbol $\cdot^{\vee}$ while the hat operator to $\hat{\cdot}$

$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\cdot^{\vee} : g \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n 
\\
\hat{\cdot}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow g \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$

These two operators allow to move from the manifold to a tangent space to the manifold in the considered point and back.

I also know that the link between a Lie Group and its associated Lie algebra can be expressed with the exponential (exp) and logarithmic (log) operations.

**QUESTION:** Does it mean that the vee/hat operators are the same thing of the exp/log maps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a reference? As far as i know these are not standard notations (in pure mathematics literature at least).

Comment: This is the paper where I found this. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7487292/

Thanks for the comment

Comment: The authors define $\widehat \cdot$ to be a linear isomorphism from the Lie algebra $\rm g$ to $\mathbb R^n$, and $\cdot^\vee$ as the inverse of this isomorphism - as they say, this is just an abstract way of choosing a basis for $\rm g$. The group isn't involved at all in these operations.

Comment: So you are telling me that there is no link between vee/hat operators and exp/log maps? 

Thanks for taking the time to reply to me.

Comment: Yes - you could *combine* them with exp/log to get useful maps from the group to $\mathbb R^n$, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: The notations vee/hat are useful in applied mathematics, when one considers matrix Lie groups, hence defining a Lie group as a subgroup of GL(n) [= group of invertible matrices). Here, by definition, Lie algebra are square matrices, but practically, there are often more complex representation for Lie Algebra elements. For instance, for SO(3) it is more practical to represent the element of the Lie Algebra (= tangent vector) as a 3-vector, and hat/vee are merely trivial mappings to map from such a compact representation to a square matrix. Boring for pure mathematicians, but useful for coders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I finally understood the link between hat/vee map and exp/log map.

The answer to my question is NO. Hat/vee map is not the same thing of exp/log map. As pointed out also in some comments.

Assume we have a Lie Group $G$ and its associated Lie algebra $g$.

As I wrote in my question the vee/hat maps are defined as

$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\cdot^{\vee} : g \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n 
\\
\hat{\cdot}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow g \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$

The Vee operator $(\cdot^{\vee})$ is the operator which allows to move from the Lie algebra $g$ to the real vector space of dimension equal to the one of the Lie algebra.

The Hat operator $(\hat{\cdot})$ is the operator which allows to go backward (w.r.t. the vee operator).

On the other side, the $exp$ map allows you to describe the shortest path from the identity of the group $G$ to another point. You can write this as

$
\begin{equation}
exp(\mathbf{S})
\end{equation}
$
where $\mathbf{S} \in g$

In the case your $G$ is the Lie Group of the rotations $SO(3)$ the exponential map allows you to go from an orientation to another one.

Another way of seeing it is that the exponential map allows you to go from a manifold to a tangent space to the manifold. The logarithmic map does the opposite.

This should be right but I am really open to discussion.